# SQL Query for finding the highest mark

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working on a small application

I have two demo table `studentdetails` and `studentmarks`...

The `studentdetails` table have the following column:

```
student_id(primary key), name, batch, address and telephone number
```

The `studentmarks` table have the following column:

```
student_id (foreign key to student_id column of studentdetails), physics, maths, english, chemistry
```

My question is how do i find the highest mark achieved by students by each subject???

The output will be: `(name, subject, marks)`.

Is this possible with my given structure?

sample data for `studentdetails`:

```
-------------------------------
    (001, studentname1, 01, Address1, 1234567),
    (002, studentname2, 01, Address2, 2345678),
    (003, studentname3, 01, Address3, 3456789)
```

sample data for `studentmarks`:

```
-------------------------------
    (001, 77, 87, 99, 70), 
    (002, 92, 68, 97, 80), 
    (003, 88, 78, 90, 66)
```

Comment: Which Database you are using Sql server or Mysql both are different. Also include the expected output

Comment: im currently using sql server 2012, building an asp.net application

Comment: the output will be in this format (subject, name, marks)

Comment: can you add sample data for marks table

Comment: (001, 77, 87, 99, 70), (002, 92, 68, 97, 80), (003, 88, 78, 90, 66)

Comment: It would be better if you included sample data and required output in the OP, instead of citing them in the comments area

Comment: And required output based on the given sample data?

Comment: yup the sample data can be used for the required output

Comment: And the required output is ... does it contain one record for each student, or one record for each subject ...?

Comment: it should output every subject's highest mark, along with name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT student_id, Mark, Subject
FROM 
   (SELECT student_id, physics, maths, english, chemistry
    FROM studentmarks) p
UNPIVOT
   (Mark FOR [Subject] IN 
      (physics, maths, english, chemistry)
   )AS unpvt;
```

to get a flat list of *mark per subject* for each student:

```
student_id  Mark    Subject
===========================
001         77      physics
001         87      maths
001         99      english
001         70      chemistry
002         92      physics
002         68      maths
002         97      english
002         80      chemistry
003         88      physics
003         78      maths
003         90      english
003         66      chemistry
```

Using the above in a `CTE`:

```
;WITH MarkPerSubject AS (
 .... unpivot query here
)
SELECT name, Mark, Subject
FROM (
   SELECT m.student_id, s.name, Mark, Subject,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Mark DESC) AS markOrder
   FROM MarkPerSubject AS m
   INNER JOIN studentdetails AS s ON m.student_id = s.student_id
) t
WHERE t.markOrder = 1
```

can give you the highest mark per subject:

```
name    Mark    Subject
------------------------
Alex    80      chemistry
Jon     99      english
Jon     87      maths
Alex    92      physics
```

Note the use of `DENSE_RANK()`: if two or more students have the highest mark in a subject, then the result will contain one record for each of these students for this specific subject.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, was looking for highest mark per subect

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a 'subjects' table instead and replace your physics, maths, english and chemistry columns to a single 'subject_id' instead (more flexible)

However, going on what you have now - assuming that the mark is a number - I think this'll work.

```
SELECT a.student_id
     , a.name
     , a.batch
     , a.address
     , a.telephone_number
     , b.max_physics
     , b.max_maths
     , b.max_english
     , b.max_chemistry
  FROM studentdetails a
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT z.student_id
                   , MAX(z.physics) AS max_physics
                   , MAX(z.maths) AS max_maths
                   , MAX(z.english) AS max_english
                   , MAX(z.chemistry) AS max_chemistry
                FROM studentmarks z
               GROUP BY z.student_id
            ) b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
```

Comment: i know that would have been a better idea, but this structure was given to me... thanks...

Comment: thanks for the help... but i want the output in the following format, (name, subject, mark), is this possible with my given structure

Comment: Ah, so for each student, you want to show their highest scoring subject and mark, ignoring the lower scoring ones?

Comment: this is what i intend to do